# trying to reference javascript from asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web page in ASP.net and C# (I'm using visual studio 2010 if that helps at all), and I wanted to get a modal popup box going after a button click event.  I can't use AJAX because I'm not allowed to install the extension on the server...so I have tried out the javascript method provided by [yensdesign](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/).

The problem I have is that the button I've set up just doesn't do anything...I am guessing that since I am calling this from an asp.net web page instead of standard html I need to do something extra but a day of googling, asking everyone I know, and trial and error have not yielded any results so here I am...

I have the following in my 'scripts' folder called popupAdminTasks.js:

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
/***************************/

//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup() 
{
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatus == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup() 
{
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if (popupStatus == 1) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup() 
{
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    //only need force for IE6
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {

    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#btnViewTimesheet").click(function () {
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupBtnClose").click(function () {
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopupAdminTasks").click(function () {
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 && popupStatus == 1) {
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

So that's great.  I then have my css file which has all the normal stuff in it, with the extras at the bottom as follows:

```
/* POPUP BOX  
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#backgroundPopup
{  
    display:none;  
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/  
    height:100%;  
    width:100%;  
    top:0;  
    left:0;  
    background:#000000;  
    border:1px solid #cecece;  
    z-index:1;  
} 

#popupAdminTasks
{  
    display:none;  
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/  
    height:384px;  
    width:408px;  
    background:#FFFFFF;  
    border:2px solid #cecece;  
    z-index:2;  
    padding:12px;  
    font-size:13px;  
}  

#popupAdminTasks h1
{  
    text-align:left;  
    color:#6FA5FD;  
    font-size:22px;  
    font-weight:700;  
    border-bottom:1px dotted #D3D3D3;  
    padding-bottom:2px;  
    margin-bottom:20px;  
}  

#popupBtnClose
{  
    font-size:14px;  
    line-height:14px;  
    right:6px;  
    top:4px;  
    position:absolute;  
    color:#6fa5fd;  
    font-weight:700;  
    display:block;  
}  

#btnViewTimesheet
{  
    margin:100px;  
}
```

Wonderful.  So now we come to the actual aspx file...well this is a bit more tricky as obviously I'm not just doing a test project so instead of having a head section, I have a headcontent section etc...anyway, here's the relevant bits and bobs:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/AdminPage.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="../Scripts/popupAdminTasks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="btnViewTimesheet">
        <input type="submit" value="View/Edit Timesheet" />
    </div>
    <div id="popupAdminTasks" runat="server">
        <a id="popupBtnClose">X</a>
        <h1>What would you like to do?</h1>
        <p id="popupAdminTasksBody">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCalendar" runat="server" Height="70px" Width="65px"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png" AlternateText="View/Edit Timesheet" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopupAdminTasks">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

So...This all builds without error, but I press the button `btnViewTimesheet` and nothing happens...any ideas??  The thing I keep thinking is that I don't have an on-click event in the C# code and I would have thought I would need this, and point to the js code from that event but everything I have read and people I've spoken to have told me that no, I shouldn't need this, because the javascript should do it.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I haven't studied your code, but I'm thinking it might have to do with `runat=server` tags and `NamingContainers` renaming the id's of controls.

Comment: AJAX does not requite a server extension.

Comment: .NET wants to own all of the element IDs. If you are hooking up event handlers in JS, use CSS class names instead.

Comment: can you show your popup markup? Most, it not all of the selectors in your jquery don't seem to exist in your current markup sample. Where's the markup for `#backgroundPopup` and `#popupContact`?? These are the elements being shown when you click the button.

Comment: @Diodeus that is only true for *server* controls. You can certainly use plain vanilla elements and "control" their IDs and hook them up to any Javascript. Even server controls can be used (`ClientID` and `ClientIDMode`)

Comment: I would guess that your submit is posting to the server and refreshing your page before your javascript executes. (Assuming the submit is within a form) Try adding `onclick="return false;"` to your submit input.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, interesting about AJAX - I know it doesn't need the toolkit but thought it needed the extension.  If not that will probably be my easiest bet!  @Bill - I will give it a go now, thanks

Comment: @KP. - I did put it up there; the #backgroundPopup relates to the <div id="backgroundPopupAdminTasks"> section and so forth...

Comment: @BiffMaGriff - I tried this, didn't change anything - I then read up a bit more and tried adding it to the OnClientClick bit which I added following the answer from 03Usr but still didn't change anything... :(

Comment: @Elatesummer I had another look at your code. It looks like we are putting the horse before the cart. In your javascript you are referencing `#backgroundPopup` and `#popupContact`. And you have no such elements with those IDs in your html. Perhaps you mean to use `#popupAdminTasks` instead. Your click javascript is executing but it can't find those controls. http://jsfiddle.net/2mSkM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the wrong element ID's in your jQuery selector.

You should change `backgroundPopup` to `popupAdminTasks` and `popupContact` to something else.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mSkM/

Comment: Thank you - I see you also added this as a comment but I'm glad you proposed this as an answer so I could upvote and accept.  I tried this and it did indeed resolve my issue - also thank you for bearing with me throughout this!

Answer (score 3):

> I can't use AJAX because I'm not allowed to install the extension on the server...

AJAX isn't installed on any server. Its just Javascript. I haven't used ASP.Net AJAX extensions in years, so I forget if even that needs to be installed at all or just bin-deployed. Regardless, taking advantage of "Ajax" isn't dependent on any extension/library - they make things easier, but they are not "required".

## #

- Your `id` is for the `<div />` not the input
- Your `<input />` is a submit, while you can still use that, try a button instead to make things easier

Comment: I have also tried a button - tried the submit as another approach.  Neither of them worked...but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: marked this as the answer...if the extensions aren't required, I will just use AJAX...it isn't really the solution to my question but this answer enabled me to get the end result - thanks, EdSF

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do the following?

```
<asp:button runat="server" text="Click Me" OnClientClick="javascript:loadPopup()" id="myButton"></asp:button>
```

Comment: I tried this and still nothing happens...then I tried changing the OnClientClick to: OnClientClick="javascript:loadPopup(); return false;" as per the comments on the main post but still doesn't work...no action following the click